# Does WSO2 have a OPCUA connector?

Tags: opc-ua, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

Does WSO2 ESB or WSO2 EI have a OPC UA connector?

We need to access a SCADA system via OPC using a WSO2 product (either ESB or EI).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [no out-of-the-box support](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB470/Features) for OPC UA on WSO2. Supported protocols to integrate your existing network and applications as listed below:

- Non-blocking HTTP/S transport
- Transactional JMS transport 1.0 and 1.1 with binary, text and SOAP messages over JMS
- Apache VFS file transport (for example, S/FTP, File, zip/tar/gz, WebDAV, CIFS, etc.)
- Mail transport (POP3, IMAP, SMTP) with multipart content support
- AMQP via Apache QPid
- Financial Information eXchange (FIX)
- Hessian binary protocol for web services